# How to make variable names human-readable in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, janitor

Is there a dedicated function that does the opposite of `janitor::clean_names` and converts clean variable names to presentable names:

e.g. "my_variable_names" becomes "My variable name".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
janitor::make_clean_names("my_test_title",case = "sentence")
# [1] "My test title"
```

Edit (to match the question better):

---

```
data.frame(my_test_title = c(1)) %>% janitor::clean_names(case = "sentence")
#  My test title
#1             1
```

Comment: You can see all options with `??snakecase::to_any_case`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `gsub/sub` or `chartr` to do the conversion i.e. replace the `_` with space `" "` and then make the first letter upper case

```
sub("^(.)", "\\U\\1", gsub("_", " ", str1), perl = TRUE)
[1] "My variable names"
```

---

If we need a package solution, then use `to_sentence_case` from `snakecase`

```
library(snakecase)
to_sentence_case(str1)
[1] "My variable names"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "my_variable_names"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this certainly works. I am wondering if there is a dedicated function that does this automatically, as `clean_names` does.

Comment: @prayner you may use `snakecase::to_title_case(str1)`

Comment: @prayner I updated the post.  If it works, please consider to upvote/accept soluiton. thanks